# Using the right Web Scraper

Tags: web-scraping, webharvest

I need to make a web scraper that uses an input address from the client, and then retrives data from that address from a specific site. I downloaded Webharvest, is that the right thing to begin with to learn how to write the program to do it?

Also, can someone direct me to a good tutorial to learn how to do it if possible.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a good [web-scraper comparison table](http://extract-web-data.com/software-for-web-scraping/). It may help you to choose the right scraper.